# How to use popTo in Ionic 3?

Tags: ionic3

I'm trying to implement navigation like this:

HOME -> MENU PAGE -> WIZ 01 -> WIZ 02 -> WIZ 03 -> WIZ END

and I would like from WIZ END to go back directly to WIZ 01, in order to re-start the wizard again after completing it. When I test the web app in the browser (Chrome on Windows) everything works great. But when I build and deploy the app, and I try to run it on Chrome for Android, the popTo function of NavController is not working anymore. popTo is not documented, so I tried with many other different techniques I found, like to remove the View from the stack, using Pop many times, and other I don't even remember. Nothing, I can't get it working! The only thing I could make work is popToRoot, but in this way, I lose the HOME as root, it's not the way I wanted to make it work.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: any errors in the console when you tried on device? also please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I know it is late. But I have a better solution for this.

```
this.navCtrl.getViews().forEach(element => {
     if(element.name == 'pagename'){
          this.navCtrl.popTo(element);
     }
});
```

This is working and it also make sure that you route to exact page.

Answer (score -2):

I started a new Ionic project from scratch, and I found out that popTo is not working as suggested, but I could make it work using the following way:

```
this.navCtrl.popTo(this.navCtrl.getByIndex(this.navCtrl.length()-4));
```

In my original project, this is not working anyway, so I will try to upgrade Ionic to the latest version or create a new project and copy all files to the new project.